# Does Ace (editor) have an API similar to CodeMirror's addLineWidget?

Tags: ace-editor

I am researching Ace to see whether it has all the features I need. I only used CodeMirror before, and one of CodeMirror features essential for me was `addLineWidget`, which basically inserts an arbitrary html block after a certain line in the editor ([example](http://codemirror.net/demo/widget.html)).

Does Ace have an API for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ace have somewhat similar api.

```
var LineWidgets = require("ace/line_widgets").LineWidgets;
var session = editor.session;
if (!session.widgetManager) {
    session.widgetManager = new LineWidgets(session);
    session.widgetManager.attach(editor);
}
session.widgetManager.addLineWidget(...)
```

It is used in [ace in github, error_marker.js at line 171](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ext/error_marker.js#L171).
To see it in action press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> on mac) in [ace github](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/kitchen-sink.html).

Comment: I tried your code but the widetManager doesn't have an attach method. Any hints?

Comment: Are you using old version? attach method is at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/line_widgets.js#L82 also see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/ext/error_marker.js#L94